# Create SVG triangle

Tags: svg

I am trying to create an equilateral triangle that you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/e5o7hww1/):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="22"
     height="22"
     viewBox="0 0 22 22">
  <path d = "M0 0 L0 22 L20 11" stroke = "red" stroke-width = "3" fill = "red"/>
</svg>
```

My thinking was that I put the pen at (0, 0) and then draw lines to the (20, 11)  but the triangle does not look correct.

Comment: Add a Z to close the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your triangle is *stroked*, and the stroke extends beyond the path points you supplied (as the stroke is centered on the path). This means that the stroke gets cut off at the edges of your image. Try making the image a bit larger and don't start at (0, 0). Furthermore, the path is not *closed*, so the stroke only covers two of the three sides (closing a path is not necessary when just filling it).

The following should look more like the triangle you envisioned:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="28"
     height="28"
     viewBox="0 0 28 28">
  <path d = "M3 3 L3 25 L23 14 z" stroke = "red" stroke-width = "3" fill = "red"/>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, get rid of the stroke and you can keep your view box and coordinates. It doesn't add anything here, except making the shape slightly larger.